# Duda de foreach en php

Tags: php, mvc

Tengo una duda sobre llenar una tabla recorriendo un array con un foreach.

Si lo hago sin función, sí me muestra el resultado esperado, pero lo que deseo es utilizarlo como función. Por el momento lo dejé así:

```php
<?php require_once "../controller/usuarios_controller.php"; ?>
<table align="center" border="1">
        <thead>
            <td align="center"><strong>ID</strong></td>
            <td align="center"><strong>USUARIO</strong></td>
            <td align="center"><strong>CONTRASEÑA</strong></td>
            <td align="center"><strong>DEPARTAMENTO</strong></td>
            <td align="center"><strong>PRIVILEGIO</strong></td>
        </thead>
        <?php $datos = get_usuarios(); ?>
        <?php foreach ($datos as $dato):?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $dato["id"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $dato["usuario"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $dato["contrasena"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $dato["departamento"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $dato["privilegio"]; ?></td>
            <td style="width:150px;">
                <a href="adm/editar.php?id=<?php echo $dato["id"];?>">Editar</a>
                <!-- <a class="<?php //echo $pagina == 'editar' ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="views/editar.php?p=editar&id=<?php //echo $dato["id"];?>" >Editar</a>-->
                <a class="<?php echo $pagina == 'editar' ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="?p=editar&id=<?php echo $dato["id"];?>">EDITAR</a>
                <a href="#" id="del-<?php echo $dato["id"];?>">Eliminar</a>
                <script>
                $("#del-"+<?php echo $dato["id"];?>).click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    p = confirm("¿Está seguro que desea eliminar al Usuario?");
                    if(p){
                        window.location="?p=eliminar&id="+<?php echo $dato["id"];?>;
                    }
                });
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        </table>
```

Nótese que estoy llamando al controlador que tiene la función y a `$datos` le asigno `get_usuarios();`.

Pero no sucede nada, sigue sin mostrarme la tabla llenada. El archivo donde tengo la función `get_usuarios();` está así:

```php
<?php
//Llamada al modelo
require_once("../model/usuarios_model.php");

class usuarios_controller{


    function get_usuarios(){
        $per=new usuarios_model();
        $datos=$per->get_usuarios();

        //Llamada a la vista
        require_once("../view/adm/usuarios_view.phtml");
    }
}
?>
```

El model no tiene ninguna falla puesto que lo he probado con casos diferentes, únicamente es el controller que no regresa nada a la vista. Incluso poniéndole el `return $datos;` sigue sin mandar nada.

¿Podrían explicármelo?

Comment: En el código de tu vista no veo que hayas creado una instancia de `usuarios_controller` (e.g. `$obj = new usuarios_controller();`). Además deberías de llamar así a `$datos = $obj->get_usuarios()` (No entiendo porque no ves un error). Y `get_usuarios` debería hacer `return $datos;` Intenta reforzar tus conocimientos sobre [visibilidad de métodos y propiedades de Clases](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: si le sacas la función get_usuarios de la clase? y solo manejas como función sin que sea un método de una clase. Creo que por eso no te esta funcionando. No veo por ningún lado que estés creando el objeto.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y explicación, me mostró el resultado esperado. Y claro, reforzaré mis conocimientos :D

Comment: @MarcosGallardo podrías responder la pregunta formalmente?

Comment: @ArieCwHat, seguro, ya esta hecho! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen los siguientes errores:

- En la vista, no has creado una instancia de `usuarios_controller`, es decir, te falta hacer:

  ```
  $obj = new usuarios_controller();
  ```
- En la vista, la función `get_usuarios` es un método de la clase `usuarios_controller`, por lo que deberia ser invocada así:

  ```
  $datos = $obj->get_usuarios()
  ```
- En el controlador, `get_usuarios` debería devolver la variable `$datos`, es decir:

  ```
  return $datos;
  ```

Lectura recomendada: [Visibilidad de métodos y propiedades de Clases](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php)